In a single call Get all the Users in a group along with the number of groups that each user belongs to?
we are using the following query to get the list of all the members in a group
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}/members
requirement

We need to get all the users in a group and also the count of the groups each users belongs too in a single call, so that we dont delete users who are part of multiple groups.

couldn't find any information on searching on multiple entities (group and user).

Do you want to fetch the results in c#?

With a single query, you can retrieve users members of a specific group and expand groups where the user is a member of.
GET /v1.0/groups/{group_id}/members/microsoft.graph.user?$expand=memberof/microsoft.graph.group($select=id)

Counting must be done on the client
If you prefer the Microsoft Graph .NET SDK
var result = await graphClient.Groups["{group-id}"].Members.GraphUser.GetAsync((rc) =>
{
    rc.QueryParameters.Expand = new string []{ "memberof/microsoft.graph.group($select=id)" };
});

var pageIterator = PageIterator<User, UserCollectionResponse>.CreatePageIterator(graphClient, result, (user) =>
{
    var groupCount = user.MemberOf.Count;
    return true;
});

await pageIterator.IterateAsync();


Awesome!!!  it's working but returning only 100 users and their groups, we have about 145 users

@nen You need to implement paging, check updated answer. By default only 100 members are returned.

Make use of below code to get all the users in a group and also the count of the groups each users belongs too in a single call:
namespace GraphGroupMembers
{
    class Program
    {
        private static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            
            string tenantId = "TenantID";
            string clientId = "ClientID";
            string clientSecret = "ClientSecret";
            var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);

            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" });

            var groupId = "GroupID";

            var result = await graphClient.Groups[groupId].Members.GraphUser.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
            {
                requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Expand = new string[] { "memberof/microsoft.graph.group($select=id)" };
            });

            
            foreach (var user in result.Value)
            {
                if (user != null)
                {
                    var groupCount = user.MemberOf?.Count ?? 0;
                    Console.WriteLine($"User: {user.DisplayName}, Group Membership Count: {groupCount}");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



top 200, does not work.
